# Custom error pages in servicestack

Tags: servicestack

How do I configure ServiceStack to serve specific error pages (404, 500, etc.) depending on the type of error being returned?

Currently, I'm using the RawHttpHandler below code to ensure that a request for a HTML file is authenticated. However, if the user specifies a non-existent file or endpoint, how can I have it return my 404.html page.

```
  this.RawHttpHandlers.Add(httpReq =>
            {
                var session = httpReq.GetSession();

                if(!session.IsAuthenticated) {
                    var isHtmlFileRequest = httpReq.PathInfo.EndsWith(".html");

                    if(isHtmlFileRequest && !files.Any(s => httpReq.PathInfo.ToLower().Contains(s))) {
                        return new RedirectHttpHandler {
                            AbsoluteUrl = "/Login.html"
                        };
                    }
                }

                return null;
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Error Handling wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling) shows different ways to [Customize Handling of Exceptions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#customize-handling-of-c-exceptions) in ServiceStack, e.g you can redirect 404 errors to `/404.cshtml` with:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    this.CustomHttpHandlers[HttpStatusCode.NotFound] = 
        new RazorHandler("/404");
}
```

CustomHttpHandlers can be any `IServiceStackHandler` which is just a HttpHandler that supports both ASP.NET and HttpListener requests. The easiest way to create one is to just inherit from `IServiceStackHandler`. Here's an example of a Custom Static File Handler similar to [StaticFileHandler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/Handlers/StaticFileHandler.cs) except it only writes the specified `filePath` instead of using the HTTP Request path:

```
public class CustomStaticFileHandler : HttpAsyncTaskHandler
{
    string filePath;
    public CustomStaticFileHandler(string filePath)
    {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        var httpReq = context.ToRequest(GetType().GetOperationName());
        ProcessRequest(httpReq, httpReq.Response, httpReq.OperationName);
    }

    public override void ProcessRequest(IRequest request, IResponse response, 
        string operationName)
    {
        response.EndHttpHandlerRequest(skipClose: true, afterHeaders: r =>
        {
            var file = HostContext.VirtualPathProvider.GetFile(filePath);
            if (file == null)
                throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found");

            r.SetContentLength(file.Length); 
            var outputStream = r.OutputStream;
            using (var fs = file.OpenRead())
            {
                fs.CopyTo(outputStream, BufferSize);
                outputStream.Flush();
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be registered as normal, i.e:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    this.CustomHttpHandlers[HttpStatusCode.NotFound] = 
        new CustomStaticFileHandler("/404.html");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have seen that before, but wasn't sure how to make it work without Razor. Do I have to install the Razor package? I'm not using it at the moment.

Comment: In other words, is there a file handler or something that I can use to simply serve an html file?

Comment: @theoutlander Yes RazorHandler needed `ServiceStack.Razor` NuGet package. I've updated the answer with an example that shows how to serve a static file.

Comment: I've combined the Custom Handler with code that validates authorization to resources.